# Get the highest height value from collection of DOM elements

Tags: javascript

I have a div with some children. I need to get the height of the highest div from those children. What is the best way, to get it using JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/56XzW/

```
var max = Math.max.apply( null, $('#mydiv').children('div')
                                           .map(function(){
                                               return $(this).height();
                                           }).get() 
                        );

alert( max );
```